# EF Core code first Inheritance of separate table

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

Say I have a table Company defined in following entity:

```
public class Company
{
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Uid { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And I need another table CompanyHistory what will have all fields of Company extended with CompanyHistoryId, EffectiveDate, DEffectiveDate.
I have tried it like this:

```
public class CompanyHistory : Company
{
    public Guid CompanyHistoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company { get; set; }
}
```

But instead of 2 tables migration makes one and combines all the columns.

How can I get same result without writing all the column again as is done here:

```
public class CompanyHistory
{
    public Guid CompanyHistoryId { get; set; }

    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Uid { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: you can inherit your class

Comment: I did inherit it, just forgot to write it. I have edited the question now. But still instead of 2 tables I get only one in Db.

Comment: Answer is NOT at the moment,but can be achieved using different structure (abstract CompanyBase class)
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8728